# Should I always use a hyphen to make clear what an attributive describes?

Tags: hyphens

When I write "I heard his **deep warm voice** filling the room." it's clear that both *deep* and *warm* are attributives for *voice*. When I write "The **32-bit** Pentium had a **64-bit** data bus." I use the hyphen between *32* and *bit*, to make evident that *32* is an attributive of *bit*, not *Pentium*. When I write "The **well-known** actress accepted her award." I use the hyphen to avoid confusion with *well known actress*.

Should I always use a hyphen to make clear what an attributive describes? For example, should I write "She was wearing a deep-crimson shirt." to make the sentence clearer?

Comment: Related? http://xkcd.com/37/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your examples aren't exactly the same.  In your first example, you're actually missing a comma:

> I heard his deep, warm voice filling the room.

You need the comma here because both *deep* and *warm* describe *voice*.  What kind of voice is it?  A voice that is deep and warm.

> She was wearing a deep crimson shirt.

No comma here, and also no hyphen; *deep* describes *crimson*, and *crimson* describes *shirt*.  What kind of shirt is it?  A crimson shirt.  What kind of crimson is it? A deep crimson.

I think '32-bit' being hyphenated is just because it's become a convention to write it that way.  If you wrote 32 out as a word, you wouldn't hyphenate:

> The thirty-two bit Pentium had a sixty-four bit data bus.

---

ETA: Upon further research, it seems that in the first example, you can either use the comma or not use the comma; either would be correct. ([Source](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/enumeration_of_adjectives.htm))

I found [this example](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/adjectives_compound_adjectives.htm) online that illustrates when to use the hyphens. Basically they are used to avoid syntactic ambiguity; when *not* using the hyphen makes the sentence mean something else, you use the hypen.

> - Jacob took the well-fatted calf to the riverside.
>   ('well-fatted calf' as in a very plump calf)
> - Jacob took the well fatted calf to the riverside.
>   ('well fatted calf' could be construed as a 'well' (i.e., healthy) and 'fatted' calf.
>   In the first example, the 'well-fatted calf' could be ill.)

This is similar to your added example about the *well-known actress*:

If you do not use a hyphen, you have:

> The well known actress accepted her award.

In this case both *well* and *known* apply to the actress.  This means she is well (not ill) and known.  But that's not what you want to say; you want to describe to what degree she is known, and you don't mean to say anything about the state of her health.  So you use the hyphen to make *well-known* into a compound adjective everyone will understand:

> The well-known actress accepted her award.

In your *deep crimson shirt* example you don't have any ambiguity.  A shirt cannot be deep, so no one is going to be confused if you don't use the hyphen. We understand inherently that *deep* applies to *crimson* and *crimson* to *shirt*. So it seems we use the hyphen to make compound adjectives when otherwise the sentence's meaning would change.

Comment: "I heard his deep warm voice filling the room." is an actual example given from the [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/deep).

Comment: @kiamlaluno You're right; I've updated my answer with further examples and research.

Comment: It's not very natural to say "the well, known actress" meaning she's both well and known to be an actress. A more serious disambiguation by punctuation is between "the long, expected speech" and "the long-expected speech" ;-) Although in that example you'd still more naturally say either "the expected long speech" (because a long speech was expected) or "the expected speech, which was long" (to separate the length from the expectation).

Comment: Sometimes adjectives describing color are used to describe an object's appearance, and sometimes they describe a color selection made when the product was was manufactured, ordered, etc.  A hyphenated color name would suggest the latter to me.  "All employees wear deep-crimson shirts made by Acme, though some employees' shirts are so badly faded as to appear almost beige".  A shirt which is almost beige isn't deep crimson, but could still be called a "deep-crimson shirt" if the manufacturer designated it as such.

Answer (score 3):

I think that one of the rules is that you hyphenate noun phrases when they become adjectives. For example, you have **stainless steel**, but a **stainless-steel kitchen**. Similarly you can have an **oak panel**, and an **oak-panel dresser**. Using this rule a processor with **32 bits** is a **32-bit processor**.

For the same reason, I would hyphenate "deep-crimson shirt", but wouldn't hyphenate "green cotton shirt" because "green" and "cotton" are different adjectives of "shirt", and not a single noun-phrase adjective of it

Comment: But "deep crimson" is not a noun phrase; "crimson" when referring to a color (not the dye or pigment that creates the color) is an adjective to begin with.