# "hand-dug well" or "hand dug well"

Tags: spelling, writing

I'm writing a text about wells, some of them are dug by hand. On the internet I see many times the term "hand dug well" is used, but also "hand-dug well" and even "handdug well" are quite frequently used.

"hand dug well", "hand-dug well" or "handdug well", which one is correct?

(spelling correctors seem not to like the last one, so I suppose it must be one of the first two options)

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5540/should-i-always-use-a-hyphen-to-make-clear-what-an-attributive-describes This might also be a duplicate, but I'll wait and see what others think.

Answer (score 1):

The orthographic representation of collocations like this often evolve from two words (*hand written*) to a hyphenate (*hand-written*) to a single word (*handwritten*) as they become progressively more widely used. Attributives in particular attract the hyphen, because it helps the reader understand the syntax.

I judge it unlikely, however, that *handdug* will ever become common—*ndd* is just too bizarre in English orthography. If I saw it in isolation I would take it for Welsh!

Comment: The string *ndd* is rare, but it does occur in *granddaughter* and *granddad*.

Comment: @snailboat True; I had forgotten them, perhaps because familiar as they are they look wrong to me. I always write *grand-daughter* (I don't think I've ever had occasion to write the other in any manner).