# Must I hyphenate "commonly-followed economic indicators"?

Tags: hyphens

> **commonly followed** economic indicators

> **commonly-followed** economic indicators

Must I hyphenate between "commonly" and "followed"? Why? Thank you.

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5540/should-i-always-use-a-hyphen-to-make-clear-what-an-attributive-describes) although the answers aren't authoritative. Some usage books and style guides will tell you to hyphenate but the consensus on [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=hyphen+noun+phrase) seems to be that you only need to hyphenate if it avoids ambiguity, and I don't see any ambiguity here.

Comment: Many style guides advise hyphenating a compound adjective if it comes before the noun, and not if if comes after, thus 'Some commonly-followed economic indicators are X, Y, and Z', but 'X, Y, and Z are some economic indicators that are commonly followed'. A red-hot iron bar, but a bar that is red hot.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to hyphenate **commonly followed**.

I cite three well-known style manuals:

> *Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association*, 7th edition: Do not hyphenate a compound including an adverb ending in “-ly” (widely used test)
>
> *The Chicago Manual of Style*, 17th edition: A two-word phrasal adjective that begins with an adverb ending in *-ly* is not hyphenated (a sharply worded reprimand)
>
> *Associated Press Stylebook 2020-2022*: No hyphen is needed to link a two-word phrase that includes the adverb *very* and all adverbs ending in *-ly: a very good time, an easily remembered rule.*

I add the caveat that these are all *American* manuals.